# Show that : $\|x\|^{2}\ge\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}|\langle x,x_{i}\rangle |^2$

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},...,x_{n}$ orthogonal vectors from $\mathbb{H}$ , $x\in\mathbb{H}$ then prove that :

> $$\|x\|^{2}≥\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\langle x,x_{i}\rangle |^{2}$$

For all $x\in\mathbb{H}$

I don't know how I start  in the proof, I don't have any hints in this type of questions.
If someone know a book or PDF where I can find like this problem?

Comment: I guess you want those $x_j$ to be orthonormal, not just orthogonal. Otherwise the statement is not true. Take for example $\mathbb{H}=\mathbb{R}$ with scalar product given by multiplication. Now surely the vector $5$ is orthogonal to itself, but your inequality is not true (in fact only true for $x=0$).

Comment: Another example $\mathbb{C}^2$ as Hilbert space $\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}\}$ for the orthogonal system and $x=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$, $|\langle \begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}\rangle|^2+|\langle \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}\rangle|^2=2>|\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}|^2=1$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Write $$x=x_0 +\sum_{j=1}^n \langle x, x_j \rangle x_j$$ where $x_0$ is in the orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{span}\{ x_1, \dots, x_n \}$. Then use $\Vert x \Vert^2 =\langle x, x \rangle $ and use that $x_j\perp x_i$ for $i,j\in \{0, \dots , n\}$ and $i\neq j$.

Comment: please complete your idea

Comment: You stated in your question that you did not know how to start. It is useless if I write a complete solution, you will not get anything from that. I wrote an outline of the proof with small gaps that I hope you can fill. I encourage you to write a complete answer and post it as an answer, then we can give you feedback and you will gain much more insight by doing the details by yourself.

Comment: @EllenEllen May be one more little hint though, use $\langle x_0,x\rangle =\langle x_0,x_0\rangle \geq 0$.

Comment: @PeterMelech Indeed, thank you, missed that one.

Answer (score 2):

We wish to show that $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n|\langle x,x_i\rangle|^2}{\|x\|^2}\leq 1$$
$$LHS=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx^Tx_ix_i^Tx}{\|x\|^2}$$
$$=\frac{x^T(\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_i^T)x}{\|x\|^2}$$
$$=\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$$
where $A$ is an idempotent matrix.

**EDIT 1**
We know that maximum value of $\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$ is absolute value of the maximum eigen value of $A$, which is $1$ here, because $A$ is an idempotent matrix.

**EDIT 2**
I am assuming that the vectors $x_i,1\leq i\leq n$ are orthonormal, the proposition is not true otherwise, as noted in comments by Peter Melech and Severin Schraven. Also, the above argument is valid only for finite dimensional Hilbert Space.

Comment: can you complete your solution ?

Comment: You missed a square in the first line...$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\langle x,x_i\rangle |^2$. The formulation should be changed when talking about infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces

Comment: @EllenEllen, I have completed my argument now.

Comment: @PeterMelech, I don't think we are using the dimension of Hilbert Space anywhere.

Comment: I guess what Peter Melech meant was that it is no clear what $x^T$ should be in infinite dimensions. I assume this is for you the functional $y\mapsto \langle x, y\rangle$? Or do you want to make the identification with some $l^2$ space and write $x^Tx$ for some generalized summation?

Comment: Actually I do not quite understand why $A$ is orthogonal. Wouldn't that only be true if the $x_j$ where orthonormal and $n$ equals to the dimension of our hilbert space?

Comment: What @SeverinSchraven said is exactly what I meant, also $x_ix_i^T$: How is it defined for $x_i\in\mathcal{H}$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is infinite dimensional or $Ax$ where $A$ is a matrix of what size and why is it orthogonal?

Comment: Identification with an $\ell^2$ space is of course legitimate, if the Hilbert space in question is separable

Comment: @PeterMelech I think the identification is still valid, even without separability. There will be only countably many coefficients of the hilbert basis which are nonzero. But it is a bit of a technical overkill :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Ok, I'm not sure when it goes to inseparable Hilbert spaces, anyway they are "rare" and as I think not of great interest

Comment: @PeterMelech I have edited the answer, I hope it is fine now.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Noting
$$ 0\le \|x-\sum_{i=1}^n\left<x,x_i\right>x_i\|^2=\|x\|^2-2\left<x,\sum_{i=1}^n\left<x,x_i\right>x_i\right>+\|\sum_{i=1}^n\left<x,x_i\right>x_i\|^2 $$
one has
$$ 2\sum_{i=1}^n\left<x,x_i\right>^2\le\|x\|^2+\|\sum_{i=1}^n\left<x,x_i\right>x_i\|^2. $$
Since
$$ \|\sum_{i=1}^n\left<x,x_i\right>x_i\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\left<x,x_i\right>^2 $$
one has
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n\left<x,x_i\right>^2\le\|x\|^2. $$

Comment: Thank you sir @xpaul 